# No me sirve el INSERT,DELETE Y UPDATE en Crud

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subconsultas

Buenos dias Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual me piden hacer un formulario ABM y yo lo hice de la siguiente forma

esto seria el archivo editar.php donde esta el boton actualizar que lleva a otra pagina para editar los datos y luego los actualiza en el index

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hoja.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>ACTUALIZAR</h1>

<?php

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"])){

$Id=$_GET["IdCliente"];

$Nombre=$_GET["Nombre"];

$Apellido=$_GET["Apellido"];

$Direccion=$_GET["Direccion"];

}else{
$Id=$_POST["IdCliente"];

$Nombre=$_POST["Nombre"];

$Apellido=$_POST["Apellido"];

$Direccion=$_POST["Direccion"];

$consulta="UPDATE cliente SET Nombre=:clinom, Apellido=:cliape, Direccion=:clidir WHERE IdCliente=:cliid";

$resultado=$conexion->prepare($consulta);

$resultado->execute(array(":cliid"=>$Id, ":clinom"=>$Nombre, ":cliape"=>$Apellido, ":clidir"=>$Direccion));

header("location:index.php");




}

?>

<p>

</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <table width="25%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><label for="IdCliente"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="IdCliente" id="IdCliente"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td><label for="Nombre"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre" value="<?php echo $Nombre?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apellido</td>
      <td><label for="Apellido"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Apellido" id="Apellido" value="<?php echo $Apellido?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dirección</td>
      <td><label for="Direccion"></label>
      <input type="text" name="Direccion" id="Direccion" value="<?php echo $Direccion?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="bot_actualizar" id="bot_actualizar" value="Actualizar"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ABM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hoja.css">


</head>

<body>

<?php


include("conexion.php");

$base=$conexion->query("SELECT IdCliente,Nombre,Apellido,Direccion FROM cliente");

$registros=$base->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if(isset($_POST["cr"])){

$nombre=$_POST["Nombre"];

$apellido=$_POST["Apellido"];

$direccion=$_POST["Apellido"];


$consulta="Insert INTO cliente (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion) VALUES (:nom. :ape, :dir)";

$resultado=$conexion->prepare($consulta);

$resultado->execute(array(":nom"=>$nombre, ":ape"=>$apellido, ":dir"=>$direccion));

header("location:index.php");


}


//DOS FORMAS------------------------------------------------------------------------

//$registros=$conexion->query("SELECT IdCliente,Nombre,Apellido,Direccion FROM cliente")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


?>


<h1>Formulario ABM cliente_factura <span class="subtitulo"> Hecho por Santi Corso</span></h1>
<form action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"></form>
  <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr >
      <td class="primera_fila">IdCliente</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Nombre</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Apellido</td>
      <td class="primera_fila">Direccion</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr> 


    <?php
      foreach($registros as $clientes): ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->IdCliente?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Nombre?></td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Apellido?></td>
      <td><?php echo $clientes->Direccion?></td>

      <td class="bot"><a href="borrar.php?Direc=<?php echo $clientes->Direccion?>"><input type='button' name='del' id='del' value='Borrar'></a></td>
      <td class='bot'><a href="editar.php?IdCliente=<?php echo $clientes->IdCliente?> & Nombre=<?php echo $clientes->Nombre?> & Apellido=<?php echo $clientes->Apellido?> & Direccion=<?php echo $clientes->Direccion?>"><input type='button' name='up' id='up' value='Actualizar'></a></td>
    </tr>    

    <?php

    endforeach;

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Nombre' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Apellido' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Direccion' size='10' class='centrado'></td>
      <td><span class="bot">
        <input type='submit' name='cr' id='cr' value='Insertar'>
      </span></td>
    <td class='bot'>&nbsp;</td></tr>    
  </table>
    </form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

conexion.php

```
<?php


try{
$conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=cliente_factura', 'root', '');

$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$conexion->exec("Set character set utf8");  


}catch (Exception $e){

die('Error' . $conexion->getMessage());
echo "Linea de error" . $conexion->getLine();   


}



?>
```

y por ultimo el de borrar.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php


include("conexion.php");

$Direc=$_GET["Direc"];

$conexion->query("DELETE FROM cliente WHERE Direccion='$Direc'");

header("location:index.php");


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Y haciendo todo esto sigue sin actualizarme,ni insertando(via la pagina,ya que desde la base de datos si se agrega la fila), ni borrando datos.
No se cual es el error

Comment: Tus arrays $_GET y $_POST contienen datos?

Comment: Ya te lo dije en otro comentario : no uses tus variables esenciales sin antes verificarlas. Por ejemplo si `$conexion` es nula el código no va a funcionar. Algunos programadores son ingenuos y creen que las cosas siempre funcionarán por que sí y no, no es así. Debes verificar siempre.

Comment: Creo que encontre mi propio error humano, diganme si esta bien, en el isset de apretar el boton de actualizar,¿no deberia ser un !isset?

Comment: @Galbi los arrays estan todos seteados todos con eñ mismo nombre para mo confundirme y para que se sobreescriban y se entienda mejor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Todo eso me fije y aun nada

Comment: No entiendo tu último comentario ni tu ¿respuesta? (la cual, creo, debería ser un comentario). El `isset` lo puedes poner en positivo o en negativo. Lo que incidiría en una forma o en otra sería el código que haya en cada bloque. O sea `isset` evaluaría que ese dato se posteó y `!isset` evaluaría que ese dato no se posteó. Puedes evaluar de cualquiera de las dos formas. No queda claro si resolviste el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo puse porque necesitaba ayuda enreañidad lo que quiero que evalue primero es lo qie esta afuera del if

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera saber si el error que encontre subsanaría todo el codigo o hay algo mas oculto.Ya que las variables estan bien definidas(repito las misma en todos lados para que sonreescriban)y los campos,tablas,etc tambien.De verdad que no encuentro que está mal

Answer (score 0):

mucho gusto. hice le mismo proyecto y tuve el mismo problema en el UPDATE. el problema radica en que al pasarle la info desde el form no le estas pasando el valor del ID ya que no esta puesto en el form. por lo que que el WHERE te da  = "" osea nulo. esto se soludiona en la etiqueta donde va el id pasarle dicho valor. espero poder haber sido de ayuda.